# Laravel Sub-menu Within View

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

Hi I am very new to Laravel and MVC frameworks in general and am looking to create a list of links (in a view within a template) that links to some content. I am using this to display a list of nine people and to display their profile description when the link is clicked on. I have created a model of what the page looks like at https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPmqn.png. The portion that I am concerned with is in blue. Is there a way to route these links to something like /about/link2 or /about?link2 while maintaining the same exact page structure but modifying the ‘link content’ section (on the right of the link menu) to show the specific link's content? I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction, as I have literally no clue where to go with this!

Comment: Can you include some code, perhaps where the data for the links of people are coming from or what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can go about doing this.

### Templates

Create your route.

Im assuming a lot about your app here but hopefully you get the picture.  If you need help with anything in particular, be sure to update your question with the code youve tried so it will be easier to help you.

```
Route::get('about/{page}', function($page)
{
    $profile = Profile::where('name', $page)->first();

    return View::make('about')->with('profile', $profile);
});
```

Modify Template.blade.php

Put this line where you wish for About.blade.php to appear.

```
@yield('content')
```

Create your view which will extend your template

```
@extends('Template')

@section('content')
    <h2>User Profile</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>Name: {{ $profile->name }}</li>
        <li>Last Updated: {{ $profile->updated_at }}</li>
    </ul>
@stop
```

### AJAX

This solution will utilize AJAX to grab the data from the server and output it on the page.

Route for initial page view

```
Route::get('about', function($page)
{
    $profiles = Profile::all();

    return View::make('about')->with('profiles', $profiles);
});
```

Feel free to follow the same templating structure as before but this time we need to add some javascript into the template to handle the AJAX.  Will also need to id everything which needs to be dynamically set so we can easily set it with jquery.

```
@extends('Template')

@section('content')
<h2>Links</h2>

@foreach($profiles as $profile)
    <a href="#" onclick="setProfile(this);" data-id="{{ $profile->id }}">{{ $profile->name }}</a>
@endforeach
<h2>User Profile</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>Name: <span id="profile_name">{{ $profile->name }}</span></li>
        <li>Last Updated: <span id="profile_updated_at">{{ $profile->updated_at }}</span></li>
    </ul>

    <script>
        function setProfile(a)
        {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'get',
                url: 'getProfile',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    profile: $(a).data('id')
                },
                success: function(profile) {
                    $('#profile_name').html(profile.name);
                    $('#profile_updated_at').html(profile.updated_at);
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Error loading data.');
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
@stop
```

Route to handle the AJAX request

```
Route::get('getProfile', function()
{
    $profile_id = Input::get('profile');

    $profile = Profile::find($profile_id);

    return $profile->toJson();
});
```

Now, the page should not have to reload and only the profile information should be updated.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Is there a way to update the URL to display each respective profile without reloading the page?

Comment: Kind of.  Instead of setting `href` to `#`, you can set it to `#{{ $profile->name }}` and it will update it each time but maybe not to exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions here as no code posted and assuming you're using the latest version of Laravel, Laravel 5.

Lets say you have a table in your database named `users` and you have a Model named `Users` (Laravel 5 comes with the Users model as default, see `app/Users.php`). The users will be the base of our data for the links.

Firstly, you want to register a route so you can access the page to view some information. You can do this in the routes file. The routes file can be found here: `app/Http/routes.php`.

To register a route add the following code:

```
Route::get('users', ['uses' => 'UserController@index']);
```

Now what this route does is whenever we hit the URL `http://your-app-name/public/users` (URL might be different depending on how you have your app set up, i.e. you may not have to include `public`) in our web browser it will respond by running the `index` method on the `UserController`.

To respond to that route you can set up your `UserController` as so:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class UserController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {

    }

}
```

Controllers should be stored in `app/Http/Controllers/`.

Now lets flesh out the `index` method:

```
public function index()
{
    // grab our users
    $users = App\Users::all();

    // return a view with the users data
    return view('users.index')->with('users');
}
```

This grabs the users from the database and loads up a view passing the users data.

Here's what your view could look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Users Page</title>
</head>
<body>

    @foreach($users as $user)
        <a href="{{ URL::route('user', ['id' => $user->id]) }}"> 
            {{ $user->username }} 
        </a>
    @endforeach

</body>
</html>
```

The view code will loop through each user from the `$users` data we passed to the view and create a link to their user page which is different for each user based on their id (their unique identifier in the DB)

Due to the way I've named it, this would be found in `app/views/users/index.blade.php` - if you save files ending in `blade.php` you can use Laravel's templating language, blade.

Now you need to finally set up another route to respond to a user page, for example `http://your-app-name/public/user/22`.

```
Route::get('user/{id}', ['uses' => 'UserController@show']);
```

Then add the `show` method to `UserController`

```
public function show($id)
{
    // this will dump out the user information
    return \App\User::find($id);
}
```

Hope that helps a little! Wrote most of it off the top of my head so let me know if you get any errors via comment.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very bare, and it is difficult to actually help your situation without you showing any code. Just to point you in the right direction though, here is what you would need.

A Model called People, this is how you will access your data.

A controller. In this controller you will do the following

1. Get the ID of the profile you want from the functions parameters
2. Find that persons information e.g. `People::find($person_id);`
3. return the profile view with that persons data e.g. `return view('profile')->with('person', $person);`

In your view you can then use that data on that page e.g. `{{ $person->name }}`

For the page that needs to display the links to the people you would have a method in your controller which..

1. Get all the people data e.g. `People::all();`
2. Return a view with that data `return view('all-people')->with('people', $people);`

You will then need a route to access an individual person. The route will need to pass the persons ID into a controller method e.g.

```
Route::get('get-person/{id}', 
    [ 'as' => 'get-person',
      'uses' => 'PeopleController@getPerson' ]);
```

You can then use this route in your view to get the links to each person

```
@foreach($people as $person)
<a href="{{route('get-person', $person->id) }}">{{$person->name}}</a>
@endforeach
```

This would produce the list of links you want.